# make animation with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
animate = animate;
desanimate = undo animate;
```

Friends, I created a function that does an element `animate` or `'desanimate'` depending on where the scroll of the body or a div is, it's working ok, how it works?

```
<li data-animation-time="[100, 800]" data-animation-position="right" class="list-item one"></li>
```

the `first` value of the `data-animation-time` array is the `initial` value, ie the animator function should be called when the `scrollTop` pass that value, the `second` value is the `end`, the `'desanimate'` function should be called when the `scrollTop` pass that value.

Everything working as you can see here -> Codepen: http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/ogKGEP (you need scroll to see the animation happens).

Now I want to determine which way the animation to happen and which way it should end, for that I changed this attr:

`data-animation-position="right-to-left"` instead of just `right` or `left`, and i add some ifs statements to the `animation` and 'desanimation' function:

Animate:

```
var animate = function(target, position) {
    target.css('display', 'inline-block');

    if (position === 'right-to-right') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            right: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'right-to-left') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            right: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'left-to-left') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'left-to-right') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

'Desanimate':

```
var desanimate = function(target, position) {

    if (position === 'right-to-right') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            right: '245px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'right-to-left') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            left: '245px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'left-to-left') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            left: '245px'
        }, 500);
    }
    else if (position === 'left-to-right') {
        target.animate({
            opacity: 0,
            right: '245px'
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

And is not working in the 'desanimate' way, something is not working good, and i really cant see what it is.

Could someone give me a hand here? What could be doing 'desanimate' not work when I inverted step values?

Example:

```
left-to-right
right-to-left
```

[Codepen with old code working just with one side (ex: left or right);](http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/ogKGEP)

[Code pen with new code not working 100% with multiple sides (ex: left to left, left to right, right to right or right to left);](http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/dPxVKQ)

Comment: I would propose that you try to accomplish it with only CSS and maybe if something is impossible with it - use a little support from JS. Always use CSS when it is possible, simplifies things a lot.

Comment: With CSS and still give supports to IE8? I don't think this is possible @victor175

Comment: Well, you can give it a try, even if you use some unsupported properties you can surely get a shim/shiv or something similar to cover it up for you.

Comment: i think this is not a solution for my problem victor, i already made with javascript, i cant waste my time doing with css what i already did with js.

Comment: and i have just one problem with my function, i should focus my efforts on fix the problem..

Comment: What is failing to work actually? Both functions seem to be functioning properly on the example.

Comment: try scroll to the top in the second one, the desanimate will not work properly.. i'm trying to solved here, but i don't know what is the font of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emqjNM) . Just have a look and let me know whether it matches the requirement.

```
    + function($) {

        var animate = function(target, position) {
            target.css('display', 'inline-block');

            if (position === 'right-to-left' || position === 'right-to-right'  ) {
      target.css('right', '500px');
       target.css('left','' );
                target.animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    right: '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
            else if (position === 'left-to-right' || position=="left-to-left") {
       target.css('left', '500px');
       target.css('right', '');
                target.animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    left: '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
        };

        var disanimate = function(target, position) {

            if (position === 'right-to-left' || position ==="left-to-left") {
      target.css('left','' );
                target.animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: '245px'
                }, 500);
            }
            else if (position === 'left-to-right' || position === "right-to-right") {
                target.css('left','' );
      target.animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    left: '245px'
                }, 500);
            }
        };

        $(window).on('load', function() {

            var target = $('[data-animation-time]');
            var animationInitial = target.data('animation-time')[0];
            var animationFinal = target.data('animation-time')[1];
          var position = target.data('animation-position');
            var shown = false;              

            $('.container').scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (!shown && (animationInitial < scroll && animationFinal > scroll)) {
      console.log("animate")
                    animate(target, position);
                    shown = true;
                }
                else if (shown && (animationFinal < scroll || animationInitial > scroll)) {
         console.log("disanimate")
                    disanimate(target, position);
                    shown = false;
        if (position.split("-")[0] == position.split("-")[2])
        position = anti(position);
                }
            });

        });

    }(jQuery);

    var anti = function (position){
      if (position == "left-to-left")
        return "right-to-right"
        else 
          return "left-to-left"
    }
```

1. Css :- it was right 500px. so intital position of card is fixed. i changed it to dynamic based on input and whenever you are adding right(css) you have to make sure left(css) is null because if you give both right and left it will get **confused** during animation
2. left-to-right & right-to-left both have their initial and final position  same.. so no need of extra fittings.. so it will work even if you come from down
3. left-to-left & right-to-right don't have have their initial and final position same .. so left-to-left will become right-to-right in reverse loop. i did that using anti function

Comment: perfect! Can you explain what did you do?